# How to go to a route without it being logged in browser history

Tags: single-page-application, durandal-2.0, durandal-navigation

I never want my logout route to show up the browser history. How can I configure the logout route to never log to the history. I know I can call activate(silent: true) but this doesn't solve my issue.

This is how I am setting up my routes:

```
activate: function () {
        app.init('shopper');

        router
            .makeRelative({ moduleId: "viewmodels", route: app.routes.routeBase })
            .map([
                { route: "logout", title: 'Log Out', moduleId: "logout/index", nav: true, hidden: app.auth.isGuest }
            ])
            .buildNavigationModel()
            .mapUnknownRoutes("errors/404")
            .activate({ pushState: true });
    }
```

Is there something I can pass in here that will cause the logout route to never be logged in the browser history? If not, what other options do I have to accomplish never logging the logout route in the browser history. Thanks.

Comment: Why doesn't activate(silent:true) solve your issue?

Comment: Ah, don't you want to use router.navigate with replace=true?

Comment: @JosiahDaniels Thank you for your response. I am looking for some way of when I set up all the routes (see edited answer above) to indicate that the logout route should never be logged to the browser history. Would replace=true be used for this, and if so, where would I put it? Thanks!

Comment: The older browsers don't support replace, IIRC...

Comment: Why do you need to hide the history? (Explaining your ultimate goal may help people work out which solutions are viable) Is it just so people can't navigate back to one of the pages?, or something else?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

There is no water proof way to avoid a page to appear in the history. But what you can do, is add a simple Javascript to throw you back (forward), once you hit that page.

All you do is add this little script on the page that you shouldn't be able to navigate back to:

```
<script language="JavaScript"><!--
    javascript:window.history.forward(1);
//--></script>
```

Comment: The reason why I don't want logout to appear in the browser history is because when a user logs in, the login route calls goBack on the browser history to take the user to the page they were on before logging in. The edge case of a user logging in, logging out, and then logging back in leads to a situation where the user can never log back in because as soon as they login, they are taken to the previous page which was log out--essentially making it so they can never log in again. If I were to implement the solution above, wouldn't that just take me back to my login page?

Comment: I would never use history.go(-1) after logging in. Going back in history might give undesired caching issues. Especially after logging in, you don't want to send users to a previous page from the cache. Usually you would give a forward url to your login script, where the login script drops you after logging in. ... Another thing you can do I try using `header('Location: /');` after logging out. I'm not sure, but I think this also might circumvent the history entry.